# C++ friend function и namespace

Tags: c++, классы, namespace

file.cpp

```
#include "file.h"
namespace NS
{
 void f(const A &obj)
 {
   std::cout << obj.data;
 }
}
```

file.h

```
class A
{
 private: int data;
 friend void NS::f(const A &obj);
}
```

Компилятор на это ругается. Если описать NS в file.cpp до class A, то все работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, чего я не понимаю? Почему так происходит? Как сделать так, чтобы работало, когда NS в другом файле?

UPD: и в одном файле не работает. "Использование неопределенного типа А"

Comment: "Если описать NS в file.cpp до class A..." Что значит "в file.cpp до class A", если в "file.cpp" у вас нет никакого "class A"? "class A" у вас находится в file.h.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Исправляется это так:

**file.cpp** остается без изменений.

В **file.h** пишется вот что:

```
class A;

namespace NS
{
    void f(const A &obj);
}

class A
{
  private:
    int data;
    friend void NS::f(const A &obj);
}
```

---

Почему ваш вариант не работал?

Во-первых, компилятору не было известно, что такое `NS`: пространство имен или класс, или еще что-то.

Однако даже если добавить над классом `namespace NS {}`, работать все равно не будет, но в этот раз ошибка будет другая: `error: 'void NS::f(const A&)' should have been declared inside 'NS'` (c) GCC.

Будь `f` в том же пространстве имен, что и класс, `friend void f(const A &);` сработало бы без объявления функции. (Эта строчка сама была бы объявлением функции, хотя до нормального (пере)объявления ее можно было бы достать только через argument-dependent lookup.)

Почему так? Видимо разработчики стандарта решили, что объявлять функции в произвольных пространствах имен из классов в других пространствах имен - это перебор.

Answer (score 3):

Использовать дружбу с функцией можно, если только объявлена эта функцию заблаговременно. Объявлять функцию можно, но заблаговременно нужно объявить класс. Неважно в каком файле вы это будете делать, главное порядок.

```
# include <iostream>

class A;

namespace NS{
void f(const A &obj);  }

class A
{
 private: int data;
 friend void NS::f(const A &obj);
};

namespace NS {
 void f(const A &obj) {
   std::cout << obj.data; } }
```

Answer (score 3):

В языке С++ *квалифицированные* имена, вроде `NS::f`, используются только для ссылки на уже ранее объявленные, т.е. уже известные компилятору сущности. Хотите использовать квалифицированное имя - позаботьтесь о том, чтобы сущность, на которую это имя ссылается, была объявлена заранее. Упрощенно выражаясь, такие сущности должны быть объявлены выше по файлу.